# is there a good open source project to learn generics and to avoid dataset?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dataset

in my company we are using `datasets` continuously for data related operations but  i want to learn how can we use the **generics**  in c sharp

so i want to know is there any **open source project** which have used generics beautifully and customizable so i can understand well and can implement in our new project  and also please give some performance measurements of dataset vs generics so i can convince my team lead to use the generics ..

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at this white paper - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff707264.aspx

It looks at implementing the [Nerd Dinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) sample site using a number of different .Net data architectures.

Scott Hanselman also wrote a [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExtendingNerdDinnerExploringDifferentDatabaseOptions.aspx) that summarised the contents of the white paper.